# Given an ERC20 token address, how do you get the current price of a single token of the ERC20?

Tags: erc20

I'm trying to solve this problem where if I'm given an ERC20 token address such as 0xff75ced57419bcaebe5f05254983b013b0646ef5. And I do not know the name of the token. How can I get the current price for a single token of the ERC20 given the ERC20 token address?
I'm trying to do this in python and I can't seem to find an API that does this. I was searching through Coingecko but it requires the name of the token. Is there any way to go straight to the current price with the address instead of having to know the name of the token?

Thank you so much,
Tony

Answer (score 0):

You can this on-chain with using chainlink oracle. You need to import this first

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

Then write a function inside the contract

```
function getTokenValue(address _token)public view returns(uint256,uint256){
        // price feed address
        address priceFeedAddress=tokenPriceFeedMapping[_token];
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed=AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // decimals returns uint8
        uint256 decimals=uint256(priceFeed.decimals());
        return (uint256(price),decimals);
    }
```

[chainlink documentation](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/)